# Save token in a npm package inside node_module folder

Tags: node.js, cookies, npm, oauth, grpc

Is there any proper way to save auth token in a client npm package?

Because i created gRPC server in golang and gRPC client side on javascript npm package, so i generated token in the server on correct password/email auth and send a token back to the npm package, so it can save it on the package and be attaching the token to the  metadata on each request to server..

My question is if there is a secure way to save the token on the client package or if there is a proper method for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After server side authentication, you need to send the token to client and the client has to store the token in the localStorage and you can send this token for your requests to the server post authentication with the header.